# Handle Non-Angular pages in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, end-to-end

I have an application where it navigates away to an Non-Angular app for login. The basic login is like this. First, loads the angular app, then click on a button on the page. Then navigates away to a non angular app (STS implemented with IdentityServer) and logs in, Then navigates back to the angular app.

Here is the code i wrote to handle this.

```
this.login = function (userId) { 
    browser.driver.get(browser.params.host.hostname);  
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('continuebutton')).click();
    browser.driver.wait(function () {               
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//*[@id=\"body\"]/section/div[2]/div[3]/a")).click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id("UserName")).sendKeys(userId);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id("Password")).sendKeys("flisdev");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName("button")).click(); 
    }, 10000);
};
```

But this throws 'Angular not found on page" error and sometimes randomly element not found error for the link referenced by the XPath. basic flow of the login is like

> Angular App --> Non-Angualr App --> Angular App

How can i handle this kind of login?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you shift to Non-Angular App, use:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
```

code in the `beforeAll()` or `beforeEach()` functions, so that protractor gets to know that it shouldn't check for Angular on the page and will not wait for Angular to settle down. If this still doesn't fix your issue, then try giving `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` in your Angular App along with the above line. Along with that its best practice to wait for element to appear before performing actions on it to avoid errors related to element presence. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with this too before i posted the question. This will still give the angular not found error when running the tests.

Comment: @KasunKodagoda Did you try adding the line in `beforeAll()` or `beforeEach()` functions? or in `onPrepare()` function?

Answer (score 1):

In my [protractor_example](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example) github repo, I use  `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` at the page level; ie. at the top of my page object (which it looks like you're using. This made the most sense to me and should work for your situation as well, as my example also contains [a non-angular login page](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example/blob/master/pages/nonAngularLoginPage.js) (very common it seems).

Also, when using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, you don't want to use `browser.driver`. Use just `browser`.